# Reuse jQuery object from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have a `WYSIWYG` application that converts a `div` to an editor using `iframe`. The application internally uses `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` as its core library. To extend the application's feature I was thinking of using `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` which is not available in my parent `DOM`

I have two choice

Load the libraries in my parent `DOM`.Take the libraries from the `iframe` itself and start extending the application i.e `jQuery = window.frames[0].jQuery`.

The latter saves me from loading it over to my parent `DOM`, however I encountered an issue where a Dialog Select menu doesn't work as expected. It doesn't show up the options at all. The code is something like:

```
// Here I chose both jQuery from parent and 
// jQuery = window.frames[0].jQuery
div = jQuery("<div id="dialog" title="Dialog"></div>")
div.append("<select><option>Foo</option>Bar<option></option></select>")
jQuery("body").append(div)
div.dialog{appendTo:editorID} //Editor is in iframe
```

Does anyone know what happens when you do this `jQuery = window.frames[0].jQuery`? Is this jQuery object going to manipulate the iframe DOM all the time and not the parent DOM? Or is the jQuery going to work just fine with the new DOM.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying content from an iframe to the parent page is possible as long as:

Both parent page (the one hosting the iframe) and the child page (the one inside the iframe) meet the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

> Both pages must have matching:
>
> - Protocol (ex. `http:` and `https:` would fail)
> - Subdomain (ex. `http://app.domain.com` and `http://www.domain.com` fails)*
> - Domain (goes without saying `apples.com` and `oranges.org` fails)
> - Port (ex. `https://www.generic.com:8080` and `https://www.generic.com:8088` fails)

*There are ways around this

Off the top of my head, I know 2 JavaScript methods that transfer nodes:

- [`document.importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) copies
- [`document.adoptNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode)  moves

> Nodes from external documents should be cloned using [`document.importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) (or adopted using [`document.adoptNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode)) before they can be inserted into the current document. The use of [`node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) is discouraged when cloning from an external document on to the current document.

The first demo uses `importNode()` after the iframe loads to copy the body of an external page in an iframe and append it to a `<section>` (any block element can be used).

The second demo uses `importNode()` on a click event. To see the results, click the button, then scroll down.

**Note:** This procedure can apply to `<script>` blocks as well.

### http://plnkr.co/edit/yUW2CYqDqrvEq5fT1ty6?p=preview

**JavaScript**

```
iFrame1.onload = function() {
  bodySnatcher('#iFrame1', '#display');
}
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  bodySnatcher('#iFrame2', '#display');
}, false);

function bodySnatcher(iframe, parent) {
  var iFrame = document.querySelector(iframe);
  var iBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var imported = document.importNode(iBody, true);
  document.querySelector(parent).appendChild(imported);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery caches a reference to the document. However, you can borrow jQuery from the same-origin iframe, and you'll primarily be unable to rely on `$(selector)` implicitly searching inside the document - instead, you can do `$(document).find(selector)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery = $(window).parents().frames[0].jQuery
//parent()
```

Comment: How is this different from mine? Remember I don't have `$` to begin with in my `parent` DOM.

Comment: Some sort of explanation to help the OP understand the solution you are proposing would be really useful here, rather than just posting a single line of code.